# В footer Wordpress неверная кодировка

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста где копать?
На сайте с движком Wordpress везде русский язык, но в футере 2 места с неверной кодировкой, в header.php и wp-config, в базе данных и в htaccess указана кодировка utf8 во всех местах, но всё равно не меняется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я изменяю через админку добавляя единички, то в админке нормальная кодировка, а на выходе нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В базе не верно записано. Переписать это и всех делов.

Comment: А через какой файл в базу это записывается?

Comment: Через админку, естественно.  Про файлы забудь.

Comment: Попробовал через админку, не получилось, в админке норм всё, добавил информацию и скрины ещё

Comment: шрифт такой? попробуйте сменить для теста